# MS Access Admin State During Statement Execution

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, locking

**Background**

I develop a number of tactical data capture tools all of which use the same approach of a split front and back end as below:

- Excel VBA forms based front end (using ADO to connect to the back end)
- Access 2007 (accdb) database as a back end

My preference would be to use SQL Server as a back end but this is not possible due to restrictions that I am not able to solve.

Each tool distributed has a varying number of users using the tools at the same time (anywhere between 10 - 300+). I understand that Access is not the ideal solution giving the potential number of concurrent users but once again, this is out of my control.

When the tools are in use, users sometimes receive the `The database has been placed in a state by user 'Admin' on machine '***' that prevents it from being opened or locked.` error.

Given the volume of transactions, the error occurs roughly 0.001% of the time.

I've read a number of articles on the topic, the majority of which end with an assumption that an object within the database is being modified or that a user is entering `Design Mode` which should be addressed by having a separated front and back end.

**Question**

A number of different types of queries occur including `SELECT` and `INSERT INTO` statements. The users do not directly access the database file and therefore no object as being modified and nothing is being put into `Design Mode` therefore why are users experiencing this error? Is it due to the shear number of users?

I use the same approach towards connecting to the database using the below method:

```
Public Function fGetOrderStatus() As Variant()

Dim oDB As ADODB.Connection
Dim oCM As ADODB.Command
Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset

On Error GoTo Err:

Set oDB = New ADODB.Connection
oDB.Open gcConn
Set oCM = New ADODB.Command

With oCM
    .ActiveConnection = oDB
    .CommandText = "SELECT OrderStatusId, OrderStatus FROM ct_elh_OrderStatus WHERE Deleted Is Null"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    Set oRS = .Execute
End With

If Not oRS.BOF And Not oRS.EOF Then
    fGetOrderStatus = oRS.GetRows()
Else
    Erase fGetOrderStatus
End If

oRS.Close
Set oRS = Nothing
oDB.Close
Set oDB = Nothing

Exit Function

Err:
    MsgBox ("An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later."), vbCritical, "Error"

End Function
```

Comment: Are they sharing the mdb/accdb?

Comment: @Elias what do you mean shared sorry? They access the db through a front end.

Comment: Do they all open the same access file or do they each get their own copy of an original "template"?

Comment: They all access the same file through an excel front end

Comment: Sorry about that I missed that part in your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to be the cause of this error:

*Jet locks a block of 256 bits in the MDB header. Included in this block of bits are bits that indicate a "passive shutdown", which causes the error message described in the "Symptoms" section to occur. You may have users that open and close the MDB file rapidly and the bits are not getting unlocked quickly enough. When a user tries to open the MDB file, if the program is not able to read the bits, Jet assumes that the user is in a "passive shutdown" or "admin mode", and therefore will not let the user open the MDB file.*

It seems this error is due to the fact that you open and close your database to rapidly, especially if there are multiple users involved.
Why not open the connection when opening the user's front-end, and closing the connection when the user wishes to quit?

More information to be found [here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274211)

Comment: Thanks was an interesting read. I haven't been able to find the same article applying to MS Access 2007 for accdb databases. I'll have a go at opening the connection at the start of the application and closing at the end though and see if it does the trick.